# Div/0 in Calculated Field VBA Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, division

I am trying to remove my 'Div/0' error on my outputted Excel Sheet using my VBA Code.

My calculated field "AFC_pct" is causing the Div/0 error. I am unable to use the =IfError function because I keep getting a compile error

```
.CalculatedFields.Add "ACD_hrs", "=ACDTime/3600"
.CalculatedFields.Add "AuxOut_hrs", "=AuxOut/3600"
.CalculatedFields.Add "Avail_hrs", "=Avail/3600"
.CalculatedFields.Add "Other_hrs", "=Other/3600"
.CalculatedFields.Add "AFC_hrs", "=AFC_Time/3600"
.CalculatedFields.Add "AFC_pct", "=AFC_hrs/ 'Daily_SchdHrsWrk'"
=IfError("AFC_pct",0)
```

Comment: Wrap the original AFC_pct formula with the `Iferror` - something like `=Iferror(AFC_hrs/ 'Daily_SchdsHrsWrk', 0)`

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the errors in the PT properties.

Pivot Table Options > Layout & Format > For Error Values Show

Check the box and leave the value blank, or enter the value you want to display.

[image]